# Lxml Get all itens but test the next one as well - Python

Tags: python, parsing, lxml

I'm, in trouble trying to parse this lxml. I'm using python language, 3.6.9.

It is something like this.

```
<download date="22/05/2020 08:34">
    <link url="http://xpto" document="y"/>
    <link url="http://xpto" document="y"/>
    <subjects number="2"><subject>Text explaining the previous link</subject><subject>Another text explaining the previous link</subject></subjects>
    <link url="http://xpto" document="z"/>
    <subjects number="1"><subject>Text explaining the previous link</subject></subjects>
    <link url="http://xpto" document="y"/>
    <link url="http://xpto" document="z"/>
</download>
```

Currently, I'm able to get all the links (which is something easy to accomplish) using this function:

```
import requests
from lxml import html 
response = html.fromstring(requests.post(url_post, data=data).content)
links = response.xpath('//link')
```

As I pointed at the lxml, the subjects, when exists, are designed to explain the previous link. Sometimes, it can have more than one subject (Like the example above, one of the subjects has the number 2, which means it has two 'subject' items inside, but the other 'subjects' has just one subject). It is a large lxml file, so this difference (a lot of links until it has one link with one explanation after) occurs very often.

How can I build a query to get all these links and, when exists the subjects next to it (after the link, to be more precise), put it together or insert it into the link as well?

My dream would be something like this:

```
<link url="http://xpto" document="y" subjects="Text explaining the previous link| Another text explaining the thing"/>
```

A list with both links and subjects together would help a lot as well.

```
[
[<link url="http://xpto" document="y"/>], 
[<link url="http://xpto" document="y"/>, <subjects number="2"><subject>Text explaining the previous link</subject><subject>Another text explaining the previous link</subject></subjects>],
[<link url="http://xpto" document="y"/>], 
]
```

Please, be free to suggest something different, of course.

Thank you, folks!

Comment: What do you mean by "Sometimes, it can have more than one subject."? Can you edit the question and add an example of a case like that?

Comment: Hey, @JackFleeting, 
I've just added some more explanation. It's a list with a lot of 'link' categories', but the 'subjects' part shown after the link actually gives us explanation about the link itself. It's really weird... As it is something related to the link, it would be easier if it goes inside. But this is not the way the server responds... too bad. Thanks for your attention!

Comment: @JackFleeting I'm thinking I'll have to do a 'for loop'. Maybe there is a better way to do it with pure lxml - which I'm not very good by the way...

Comment: Am I understanding correctly: you want all the `<link>` elements, but when the are followed by a `<subjects>` element, you need those too?

Comment: That’s right, @Grismar

Comment: Then the answer below should answer your question, but feel free to ask for clarification if it doesn't.

Comment: There's a relatively simple way to do it, but it requires using the `string-join()` method, which is an xpath 2.0 method and not supported by lxml. It is supported by another library called elemenpath; if you can use it, it's possible to get you your "dream" output.

Comment: Cool! I'll take a look, @JackFleeting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what I think it is you need:

```
from lxml import html

example = """
<link url="some_url" document="a"/>
<link url="some_url" document="b"/>
<subjects><subject>some text</subject></subjects>
<link url="some_url" document="c"/>
<link url="some_url" document="d"/>
<subjects><subject>some text</subject><subject>some more</subject></subjects>
"""

response = html.fromstring(example)
links = response.xpath('//link')
result = []
for link in links:
    result.append([link])
    next_element = link.getnext()
    if next_element is not None and next_element.tag == 'subjects':
        result[-1].append(next_element)

print(result)
```

Result:

```
[[<Element link at 0x1a0891e0d60>], [<Element link at 0x1a0891e0db0>, <Element subjects at 0x1a089096360>], [<Element link at 0x1a0891e0e00>], [<Element link at 0x1a0891e0e50>, <Element subjects at 0x1a0891e0d10>]]
```

Note that the lists still contain lxml `Element` objects, you can turn them into strings of course, if you need.

The key step is the `next_element = link.getnext()` line. For an `lxml` `Element`, the `.getnext()` method returns the next sibling in the document. So, although you're looping over `link` elements matched with `.xpath()`, `link.getnext()` will still get you a `subjects` element if that's the next sibling in the document. If there is no next element (i.e. for the last `link`, if it's not followed by a `subjects`), `.getnext()` will return `None`, which is why the following lines of code check for `is not None`.

Comment: Hey!
Thank you. 
I thought that I would may have another option with a fully lxml query, but I think this approach is a good way to fix my issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you explain to me this getnext? I've never seen this in a for loop. Normally, I would use enumerate to such a thing.

Comment: I've added a paragraph, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the most elegant way of doing things, but it gets the job done...

```
subjects= """
<download date="22/05/2020 08:34">
    <link url="http://xpto" document="y"/>
    <link url="http://xpto" document="y"/>
    <subjects number="2">
      <subject>First Text explaining the previous link</subject>
      <subject>Another text explaining the previous link</subject>
     </subjects>
    <link url="http://xpto2" document="z"/>
    <subjects number="1"><subject>Second Text explaining the previous link</subject></subjects>
    <link url="http://xpto3" document="y"/>
    <link url="http://xpto4" document="z"/>
</download>

"""
#Note that I changed your html a bit to emphasize the differences between nodes

import lxml.html as lh
import elementpath
doc = lh.fromstring(subjects)

elements = elementpath.select(doc, "//link[following-sibling::*[1][name()='subjects']]/concat('<link url=',./@url, ' document=xxx',@document,'xxx subjects=xxx',string-join(./following-sibling::subjects[1]//subject,' | '),'xxx/>')")
# I needed to use the xxx placeholder because I couldn't find a way to escape the double quote marks inside the expression, and this way is simple to implement    

for element in elements:
    print(element.replace('xxx','"'))
```

Output:

```
<link url=http://xpto document="y" subjects="First Text explaining the previous link | Another text explaining the previous link"/>
<link url=http://xpto2 document="z" subjects="Second Text explaining the previous link"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution. 
It is a little slower than the @grismar suggestion but achieved the insertion of the 'subjects' into the link. On the other hand, it saved me the need to loop through the list one more time to parse the '[[link, subjects],]' element.

```
filteredData = response.xpath('//link | //subjects') #get both link and subjects into a list
for i, item in enumerate(filteredData):        
    if item.tag == 'subjects':
        filteredData[i-1].append(item)  
        filteredData.remove(item)
```